# Bootstrap DataTable: Constructing the table with an iterator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm adding Boostrap DataTable to my project, which has some minimun requirements to work: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/

This works fine with the following code:

```
<table id="management" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-3">Serial</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Tienda</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Precio</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Estado</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3">
                <div>Column1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                <div>Column2</div>
            </td>

            <td class="col-md-1">
                <div>Column3</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                <div>Column4</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
                <div>Column5</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td hidden  >
                    <form id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" asp-action="Management" asp-route-id="@item.Id" method="post">
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                        <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" asp-for="@item.MchName" name="MchName" readonly class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-for="@item.StoreID" name="StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <input type="number" max="10" min="0" step=".5" asp-for="@item.PUnit" name="PUnit" class="form-control" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.PUnit" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                            <div>
                                <select name="Status" asp-for="@item.MachineStatus" class="form-control" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))">
                                    <option value="0">Operativo</option>
                                    <option value="1">Nuevo Item</option>
                                    <option value="2">Reparación</option>
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="@item.MachineStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                        <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.Id))" id="submit-data" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </td>
            </tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The reason why it's working is because I manually added a row on the `<tbody>` and with this, the table comply with the requirements, but of course, it can't be leaved like that.

When I remove that row and let the table be constructed with the iterator:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

I get the following errors:

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to use Bootstrap Datatable like I intend to? The errors appear because it does not take into account the rows that are being constructed with the iterator.

Maybe it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The number of rows of the header and the body should match.

In the iterator of the body there is a hidden extra column that is being made, given a total of 6 vs the 5 of the header.

Matching these numbers made it possible to work.